# How to transform a class in python into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, api, postman

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe from a class object in python.

The class object is the output of postman python script I got from the following tutorial: https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/build/meraki-postman-collection-getting-started/

I wish to take the output of this

```
print(response.text)
```

which gives:

```
[{"id":578149602163689207,"name":"Axel Network Test"},{"id":578149602163688579,"name":"Your org"},{"id":578149602163688880,"name":"Your org"},{"id":578149602163688885,"name":"Your org"},{"id":578149602163689038,"name":"Tory's Test Lab"},.......
```

I want to put this into a pandas dataframe with and ID column and name column.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations"

headers = {
    'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.0",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "7d29cb4e-b022-4954-8fc8-95e5361d15ba,1a3ec8cb-5da8-4983-956d-aab45ed00ca1",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'referer': "https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```

I tired to write

```
df = pd.DataFrame(response, columns=['id', 'name'])
```

but this produces many errors.

See error log: https://pastebin.com/4BKFYng1

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: "produces many errors": Can you provide the full error traceback?

Comment: Show us what is the error

Comment: @amanb https://pastebin.com/4BKFYng1

Comment: I think you just leaked your API key, you might want to change it ;-)

Comment: @RobinNemeth That is just the one from the tutorial do not worry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) accepts a JSON string or JSON file-like object.

```
In [10]: import pandas as pd    

In [11]: df = pd.read_json(response.text)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
                   id               name
0  578149602163689207  Axel Network Test
1  578149602163688579           Your org
2  578149602163688880           Your org
3  578149602163688885           Your org
4  578149602163689038    Tory's Test Lab
```

Comment: This one is simpler!!

Comment: This looks good but I am getting a large number of errors when I add the 3rd line "df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(response.text))". See here: https://pastebin.com/1cNbDwyc

Comment: These errors are most likely due to malformed JSON. Can you share pastebin for `json.dumps(response.text)`? Please share complete output.

Comment: @amanb Sure. Here is the output of print(json.dumps(response.text)) https://pastebin.com/VR1SAciM

Comment: @user9940344,@amanb response already serialized why would you serialize it again!!, you can issue:  df=pd.read_json(response.text)    directly

Comment: @Feras this works along with your way to drop the extra columns, I'm not entirely sure why but I am grateful! Thank you all.

Comment: @Feras, you're right, but I used it because I did not have actual reponse. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: @user9940344 my understanding that no need to serialize what is already serialized !! for this I dropped the dump function.....anyway we have a rich and positive contribution from all members, all the answers can be combined into informative blog

Answer (score 3):

As the response text is in `json`, you can:
1. Convert the json to a dict.
2. Feed the dict as a dataframe.

```
#load the json as a dict
data = json.loads(response.text)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Then you can change the name of the columns or anything else.

Comment: Add `import json` at the top

Comment: @amanb That fixed the json line but I still get the following errors with the second part of the code: https://pastebin.com/xsRKM0R9  Any ideas?

Comment: try using `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data.values(), orient='index')`

Answer (score 1):

After receiving the response, you are missing deserializing the json response to python object as @ASHu2 mentioned

```
import pandas as pd
import json 
data = json.loads(response.text)
df= pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["id","name"]) 
#Optional define index
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Comment: yeah, this is needed!! nice

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json())`

instead of this:

`df = pd.DataFrame(response, columns=['id', 'name'])`

Comment: I think this works but I get two extra columns? I get id, name and then 2 other columns "samlConsumerUrl | samlConsumerUrls". By the way could you xplain why your solution works in a brief overview?

Comment: add this step to drop extra columns df=df[['id','name']]

Comment: `response.json()` returns a python dictionary, and I use the `from_dict` method to read that dictionary into a dataframe. I see that `id 537758` has the `samlConsumerUrl | samlConsumerUrls` keys, so thats where those come from.
I'm not an expert, so I can't really get into the details of how everything works unfortunately.